# How to .append from within an Object?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, api

I'm working within WikiPedia API, (MediaWiki) and have been doing a lot of research on how to get results/push them into an array. Using Angular, I was finally able to get a successful 'forEach' to work for this matter.

My issue now is when I try to '.append' the data (An Object) to HTML, it isn't working for me. To test, I did console.log it and it's reporting the Objects and their existence to the console log, but unsure how to really push it into HTML Formatting.

I have attached a CodePen that is forked at my current state for review. I am new to Angular, so that isn't my key focus - I'm unsure why Angular can parse objects, but it does work.

```
  function wiki() {
$('#results').html('');
result = [];
search = $('#search').val();
$.getJSON(link + search, function(wikis) {
  var tempRes = wikis.query.pages;
  var page = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=';
  angular.forEach(tempRes, function(v, k) {
    result.push({
      title: v.title,
      body: v.extract,
      page: page + v.pageid
    })
    console.log(result);
    $('#results').append(result)
  })
})
}
```

The link + search variables are established early in the code, and work successfully.
Any assistance would be perfect - Been working on this bit for awhile.
[Code Pen Link](http://codepen.io/dnorthrupva/pen/gaMVZa)

Edit:

Upon further trial-n-error, my issue was resolved by modifying the Append to reflect:

```
$('#results').append('<li>' + result[i].title + '<br>' + result[i].body+ '<br>' + result[i].page + '</li>')
```

I'm thinking that just pulling result, or result[i] wasn't enough to provide proper modification. I appreciate the off-topic replies, and advice.

Comment: Are you actually using angular other than for the forEach? jQuery has a method that takes care of that... Heck, native arrays have a method that takes care of that.

Comment: @KevinB It was a work-around I found on MediaWiki - forEach didn't work on this API (At least with my level of knowledge about it) because it returns everything as an object.

Comment: The answer should be posted as an answer, not in your question. You are allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for letting me know, not completely sure on etiquette for SO. Only not regretted posting here two times.

Answer (score 1):

In order to append HTML to an element you need to build it first. Either construct your HTML tags as a string front the objects and then append, or create the elements and then append:

```
var html = "";
result.each(function () {
    html += buildHtmlFromObject(this);
});
$('#results').append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#results').append('<li>' + result[i].title + '<br>' + result[i].body+    '<br>' + result[i].page + '</li>')
```

Was the cost that resolved my issue. I needed to append the exact calls, other-wise it was trying to access an object within an object (And since the first Object is random, I couldn't forsee it.)